# Is there a way to get token price on transfer function call?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

is it possible to know for which price user is buying/selling token on transfer function call?

I want to store information on the contract for with user bought/sold tokens on the transfer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, at least in a token contract, because the token contract only "knows" that the user send or approved tokens and that's all that can know, it could be possible in a dex or cex contract

Comment: it is possible with oracles.

Comment: but how you will distinguish when the user transfer a token or is swaping tokens?

Comment: you can check only if that is realized in a single transaction

Comment: simply modify the `_transfer` function to fetch price of token before call and emit the price in modified Transfer event. Yes it must be all done in single transaction i guess that goes without saying

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. this is where oracles comes into play chainlink oracle provide off-chain data like token price feeds in contract in a decentralised way. Here is how you can get token price feed in smart contract in [EVM-compatible blockchains](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/)

To keep record of price on each transfer extend transfer event to emit the price as well that you fetch from oracle.
Your Flow for modified transfer function will be something like this.

1. All Checks to ensure (valid transfer + valid oracle call)
2. Get oracle price of token from oracle  and store it in local variable
3. Transfer
4. Emit modified event `emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount, price);` where price is current price that you got from oracle.